# SVN list directories without having the latest checkout?

Tags: linux, svn

The command `svn list` will give me list of all the sub directories in the present directory.
However,it is only restricted to directories which are present in current version.

eg. say repository url is :

"http://www.example.com/svncode/mainproduct/trunk"
and inside trunk, there are 3 directories

```
trunk/
     1/
     2/
     3/
```

If I do `svn list` it will show me all the directories `1 2 3` .
Now somebody else does a commit in trunk, which adds another directory `4` inside trunk.
Is there a way to check existence of that directory without first taking an update ? As `svn list` only provides information till latest `svn update` , not about changes that happened after that .

**Background** : I want to retreive the latest directory present inside trunk ( largest number means latest, 4 in this case), and want to checkout only that part of the trunk codebase, not full trunk .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 svn ls http://www.example.com/svncode/mainproduct/trunk
```

Comment: seems to be the required thing, will check and revert :)

Answer (score 5):

You can ls on server:

```
svn ls http://server/repo
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in *directories* and want to exclude files:

```
svn list -R http://www.example.com/svncode/mainproduct/trunk| grep -E  '/$'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers: Use `svn list` on a repository URL.

Note that if you have trouble remembering/typing the URL you can use the output of `svn info` to obtain the URL corresponding to the current working directory. In combination:

```
svn list `svn info | grep URL | cut -b6-`
```

Answer (score 0):

for SVN local use:

```
svn ls svn://yourlocaladdresssvn
```

Answer (score 0):

If the location within the repositories' paths for the  trunk-branches-tags fork is inconsistent, we have to use a filter like @bernard-de-rubinat suggests but alter it like:

```
svn ls -R https://some.server.com/svn/someRoot | grep '/trunk/$'
```

This selects only the output of the recursive ls that matches the pattern of being a string ending with .../trunk/.

That will select only directories named trunk.